# a counter example for a singular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

This one has E has answer. But I figure the Jordan canonical form cannot have 0 on the diagonal since the three vectors are l.ind. So could you please find a counter example? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let :

$$A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 &1 &0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0 \end{bmatrix}$$

and $v_1= \begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 1 \\0 \end{bmatrix}$, $v_2=\begin{bmatrix} 0\\ 1 \\0 \end{bmatrix}$ and $v_3 = \begin{bmatrix} 0\\ 0\\1 \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Thank you! are any of these in the generalized eigenspace? I figure with your matrix, the generalized eigenspace should have 3 vectors, one being the eigenvector. So the three vectors you give must not be a scalar of the eigenvector. so they must be linear combinations of the other two generalized eigenvectors?

Comment: Not with this example. Just add a one on the center of this example to get $v_2$ 0t be a generalized eigenvector, for example.